# Increase in temperature in a copper wire

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I am creating a simulation of a magnet moving relative to a copper coil generating emf in it. So far I am working with emf generated, current, resistance, resistivity, turns, coil length, and the cross-sectional area of the coil. The next step is to add the increase in temperature in the coil as a result of flow of electrons. How should I go about including that. What additional quantities do I need, including assumptions, to model that in

Answer (score 2):

With those quantities, you can only calculate heat generation. In steady state (when the temperature is constant), it will be equal to heat loss.

There are three mechanisms for heat loss: conduction, convection, and radiation. As long as the temperature is not too much higher than room temperature, the heat loss would be approximately proportional to the temperature difference. You can model it with an effective heat conductance. Time dependence depends on the thermal mass (heat capacity).

Comment: Thanks Pieter. After reading your answer and realizing I should be more precise, I reworded the question

Comment: If I use T1-T0=V^2*t/(R*m*c) to calculate temperature change, it looks like all of the energy (V^2*t/R) produced in time t is being utilized to increase the temperature of the wire when clearly most of it is delivered as electrical power, so there must be something wrong with this line of reasoning. Thoughts?

Comment: @ApolloEleven The electrical power dissipated in the resistance $R$ of the coil is precisely the heat generated in the coil, because of conservation of energy.

Comment: Here is my confusion. The energy generated is V^2*t/R in time t. Now due to conservation of energy the final energy must equal the initial. The final energy is heat energy + electrical energy delivered to the voltmeter (to be recorded). Now, when I use T1-T0=V^2*t/(Rmc) to calculate the temperature change in the coil, am I not assuming all of the initial energy is being used to raise the temperature and there is none left to "go" to the voltmeter. Can you please clarify

Comment: @ApolloEleven An ideal voltmeter carries no current. And practical electronic voltmeters are essentially ideal. So the voltmeter consumes no power (from the circuit).

Comment: Ah I see. If I am using the power generated to light a bulb, how do I calculate the temperature change in the wire given almost all of the energy "goes" to the bulb. If I use T1-T0=V^2*t/(Rmc) to calculate the temperature change in the coil, am I not assuming all of the initial energy is being used to raise the temperature